# SSIS Excel destination inserting null values on other columns

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, automation

I have 2 script components which extract data from result set objects say User::AllXData and User::AllYData.

It is run through a foreach loop and the data is stored in a data table.

Next, I'm adding the data into a excel sheet using Excel destination. Now when I do that. All the data corresponding to column A (i.e, the data from User::AllXData) is being added to the excel sheet, but the column B gets filled with null values till the end of column A's data.

Then column B gets filled leaving column A with null data. It's supposed to be aligned.

Is there a workaround for this?

Edit:
[image: An idea of what's happening]

Comment: You have two script sources inserting separate rows into the same table - of course half the columns will be null in each set of data. You probably need the script sources inserting into separate data tables and then combine the two in a third script source. How is the data meant to be aligned? You have three values in Col A but four in Col B, so it's obviously not a 1:1 alignment.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Oops, my bad. It's edited now. So you're saying the output column of the script components be used as input to another script component? Could you please elaborate on this part?

Comment: Is the source the same? Can you write a query that formats the data set the way you want? If not, add a row_number on the sorted data and do a merge join on the row_number.

Comment: @KeithL I would've sorted and merged the data but I couldn't because I wanted the data in the file as it is from my source. I came across a solution to this though, check the answer to this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long of grinding and running many tests, finally came across a solution.

The answer to this is pretty simple. Instead of using two objects as result set, it's better to use only one.

If you're going to query from a single source, include all the required columns in your SQL query into one object result set and use that as a read only variable in the script component.

Create a single data table that includes all the required columns and adds them into your excel destination row by row without any null values.

[Here's an article that has a good example](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/).